# Phonegap pushwoosh plugin registerDevice App Crash

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, pushwoosh

I am having this issue since last some days i have tried lot. I have found many solution but none of it works.

I have also tried to reinstall Android Studio and SDK. I have updated SDK too.

Still same error. Here is the Error Which I got when App Crash.

```
ATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMRegistrationService]
 Process: sample.tinfo.main, PID: 14194
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/sample.tinfo.main-1/base.apk)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
     at com.pushwoosh.GCMRegistrationService.register(Unknown Source)
     at com.pushwoosh.GCMRegistrationService.onHandleIntent(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I am using Mac OS with latest Android studio 1.5.0.

Here is the some screenshots of My Gradle File.

[image]

Here is the some screenshots of My project.properties

[image]

Here is the some screenshots of My SDK

[image]
[image]

Please Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some issue with your SDK, remove your current SDK fully and Reinstall it and Update your node-js and phoneGap version.

Answer (score 0):

Finally After long research i found the solution.

Issue was due to Facebook Plugin. As its using old jar files to it was creating problems.
Here is the steps I follow.
Hope fully it help someone else.

1. Update All the Sdk.
2. Add Push Plugin. And Remove existing Facebook plugin (if you have)
3. Now install This Facebook Plugin.(cordova-plugin-facebook4)
4. now run command ( ionic build android)

Then its working fine :)

Note: After adding facebook plugin don't go in android studio just run the ionic build android and then try to run project from android studio.